# Why is my React App not pulling API on Vercel or Nettlify?

Tags: reactjs

So I made a mini web app that uses an API from jservice.io to make a trivia app. Everything works fine until I tried deploying it on Vercel or Netlify.  The api is not being pulled for some reason on them.    Its made in React so when I made a build locally and it still works.

My only guess is that 'jservice.io' is not a secure website.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Check out the "Network" tab in developer tools to investigate what requests are being made and see if there are any errors.

Comment: Yup that was it thank you

Comment: If you solved your problem you can answer your own question explaining how you fixed it.  It’s helpful to others with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

My Site was down because the API I was using wasn't on a secure site.